# Asking for a Bus

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

I am having trouble with these Phrases...

> Is there a bus to the city?
>
> Is there a bus to town?
>
> "Is there a bus into town?"

I'm not sure if they are correct because I would usually say...

> "Is there a bus going into the city?
>
> "Is there a bus going to the city?
>
> "Is there a bus going into town?"

Comment: ***to*** here is the standard "travel destination / movement" preposition (you move ***from*** your starting point ***to*** your destination). ***into*** is a "container metaphor" in such contexts, so it only works if your destination could reasonably be seen as the kind of place you could talk about being ***inside***.

Comment: In English, it's common to omit unneeded words. In your second set of examples, there's really no need for "going" as everyone understands if you are looking for transportation *to* somewhere, you obviously want to *go* there, so *going* is left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of those wordings is OK. You can also specify the destination: Is there a bus to Cardiff? I think the forms you have with *into* are less common. Obviously if the destination is something else *into* would be wrong: Is there a bus to the top of Snowdon? or Is there a bus to the Market Place? There *into* is clearly inappropriate.